# Alignment of html pseudo-element after

Tags: css, html

How I can make center align my pseudo-element after? Like margin: 0 auto; for block elements.

```
<div>
    This is test text. This is test text. This is test text.
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
  div:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:"";

    border-color: #EAB920 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.5em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

It after element look like simple triangle. Property margin: 0 auto; does not work.

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` declaration to make `margin: auto` to work. [Example](http://jsbin.com/xaqohizudi/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the pseudo element centered horizontally *relative* to the text, you set the `display` of the targeted element to `inline-block` so that the width shrinks to fit the content. Then remove the absolute positioning from the pseudo element and `margin: auto` will work as expected.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sgskuv30/)

```css
.target {
    display: inline-block;
}
.target:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border-color: #EAB920 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.5em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">This is test text. This is test text. This is test text.</div>
```

If you don't want the pseudo element centered horizontally relative to the text, don't set the element to `inline-block` - [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/nd3wL6ty/)